# how to select the longest field for each row separately in mysql

Tags: mysql

l have a table like this

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+------+----------+----------+------+
| id | name | content2 | content3 | time |
+----+------+----------+----------+------+
| 38 | aa   | aaa      | aaaaaa   |  222 |
| 39 | b    | bbbb     | bbbbb    | NULL |
| 40 | ccc  | c        | cc       | NULL |
+----+------+----------+----------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

l want to select the longest field each row separately. So l need a result like this

```
+----+------+----------+----------+------+
| id | name | content2 | content3 | time |
+----+------+----------+----------+------+
| 41 | ccc  | bbbb     | aaaaaa   |  222 |
+----+------+----------+----------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

l'm try to use `max()` but it can just select `time` column.

l found some way and to try them, but all of them were not so good.

For example: `inner join`.

yes, it can works, but l have too much columns in my real table. By this way, it need to `inner join` 10 times if l have 10 columns.

So, is there other better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a select by column with the appropriate order and limit 1.

```
select 
(select id from test order by id desc limit 1) as id,
(select name from test order by length(name) desc limit 1) as name,
(select content2 from test order by length(content2) desc limit 1) as content2,
(select content3 from test order by length(content3) desc limit 1) as content3,
(select time from test order by time desc limit 1) as time
```

Comment: that's good ,though it is still so long, it is more beautiful than `inner join`